# How to remove negative signs in an f string expression?

Tags: python

Trying to make a random number generator that asks the user for a number and compare it with the generated one. How do I make it so that the compared number will not show a negative number?

```
    import random

number = random.randint(1, 100)
attempts = 1

print("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.")
print("You only have one attempt.")

for tries in range(attempts):
    geuss = int(input("Geuss a number: "))

    if geuss != number:
        print(f"You were {geuss-number} away!")
    elif geuss == number:
        print(f"Congratulations! You geussed the number.")
```

Let's say the number randomly generated is 63, and the user inputs 25. When the program runs, it would say You were -38 away! How would I remove the negative sign to make it say You were 38 away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd do this in f strings the same way you'd do it in any other context: by calling [`abs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs), the absolute value function.

```
print(f"You were {abs(geuss-number)} away!")
```